# Object variable not set error on Application.StatusBar

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm trying to access any method of `Application` in VBA but getting below error

[image: Error]

Code:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Loading input file..."
Application.Cursor = xlWait
```

Reference list:

[image: Reference List]

It was working fine yesterday before I leave and today facing this issue. Not getting any info on Google as well.

Any advise?

Comment: Needs a bit more code for context....  The references are likely not relevant here.  Did you maybe create a variable named `Application` ?

Comment: Without more context is kind of hard to spot a problem here.

Comment: There are way too many unknowns for this question to be answerable. Can you cook up a [mcve]?

Comment: @TimWilliams Bullseye!! I had added a module coded by another developer which have 'public Application' variable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added an module written by another developer which contain variable named `Application'

So answer here would be, whenever face this error, look in to your code for variable declaration with name `Application`.